# AS3 the width and height of swc object change to 0 WHY?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop, swc

I am developing an android application in FlashDevelop. I use SWC objects,scale and position them on the stage based on the device resolution. the strange thing is that when I play the application one of the objects wont display sometimes. when I traced the object width and height it print 0 and even when I set the width and height to a fixed size it still trace 0 and doesn't display the object on screen.The strange thing is that it doesn't happen every time I run the application. I would like to know why?? and how I can fix it?

this is the code:

```
private var txt:text002 = new text002();
public var objScale:positionScale = new positionScale();
 :

txt.x = 450;
txt.y = 10;
txt.height = 250;
txt.width = 967;
trace('before scale'+txt.height);
trace(txt.width);
objScale.cal(R, txt.width, txt.height, txt.x, txt.y, scaleDown);
txt.x = objScale.X();
txt.y = objScale.Y();
txt.height = objScale.H();
txt.width = objScale.W();
```

text002 is the swc class.
the positionScale is a class that I made to scale the SWC objects.
the trace here prints 0 before the scaling.

Comment: The only real explanation would be that the class is not yet loaded somehow? How do you embed it? Does it have children that are dynamically loaded? There's no thing like "the width is 0 sometimes" - it would have been filed as a bug years ago. The problem is within your code.

Comment: I add the class to the project by placing the swc file in the assets folder then right click and add it to the library. after that I import the class in the code.

Comment: sorry I mean use not import.

Comment: can the reason be because there are some empty frames in the swc file?